# Обновление state при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: reactjs

Я создаю небольшое приложение, которое должно вывести данные из таблицы на экран и при нажатии на кнопку "обновить" данные выводятся на страницу.

основной код :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import TransactionArr from './transaction.js';
    import Btn from './Btn';


    class App extends Component {

    constructor(props)
    {
     super(props);
     this.state = {items:TransactionArr }
    }

     sortVal  = () =>  this.setState(() =>  this.state.items.filter(w => w.value < 1000))
     sortType = () => this.setState(() =>  this.state.items.filter(w => 
     w.type == "income"))
     sortDate = () => this.setState(() =>  this.state.items.filter(w => w.dt 
     === Date ))


     render() {
      const divStyle = {color: 'blue'};
     return (
     <div className="App">
     <table border = "1" cellSpacing="0" >
      <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><Btn sortType ="value" toDoMeth={ this.sortVal  } btnName={"value"} sty = {divStyle}/></td>
      <td><Btn sortType ="type"  toDoMeth={ this.sortType}  btnName={"type"} sty = {divStyle}/></td>
      <td><Btn sortType ="date"  toDoMeth={ this.sortDate}  btnName={"date"} sty = {divStyle}/></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
       <th><p>id</p></th> 
       <th><p>value</p> </th>
       <th><p>type</p></th> 
       <th><p>date</p></th>
      </tr>
       {this.state.items.map(obj =><tr><td>{obj.id}</td><td>{obj.value}</td><td>{obj.type}</td><td>{obj.dt.toString()}</td></tr>)}
      </table>
  </div>
)
}     

  };
     export default App;
```

**код компонента кнопка :**

```
    import React from 'react';

       class Btn extends React.Component
  {

constructor(props)
{
    super(props);  
}

render()
{   
    let divStyle
    return (
        <div><button 
            style = {divStyle} 
            onClick={() => { this.props.toDoMeth();() => {divStyle = {color: 'blue'}}}} 
            btnName={this.props.btnName}>
            {this.props.btnName}
         </button></div>
        );
}
}
export default Btn;
```

При нажатии на кнопку создаются отфильтрованные обьекты, но state не обновляется (

Я не могу понять в чем причина.

Заранее благодарю.

PS

[image: вот что есть изначально в обозревателе]
[image: вот что появляется в обозревателе react после нажатия на кнопку]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `filter()` возвращает новый массив не затрагивая существующий, попробуйте сделать например так:

```
sortVal  = () =>  this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(w => w.value < 1000)})
```

И остальные по аналогии

[Ссылка на документацию filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: благодарю! ваш ответ мне помог

Comment: @Nikolay Успехов!